# get details of form through props when submitted

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I just started development with react native and i'm having difficulty getting the value of an input field through props.

Parent

```
 class HomeContainerScreen extends Component {
         state = {
             userName:'',
             passWord:''
         }

     userLogin=()=>{
        alert(this.state.userName);
     }
  render() {
    return (
     <HomeScreen 
     userLogin = {this.userLogin} 
     userName = {this.state.userName} 
     passWord =  {this.state.passWord}
     />
    );
  }
}

export default HomeContainerScreen;
```

Child

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View,Image} from 'react-native';
import { Container, Content, Form, Input, Item, Label, Button} from 'native-base'
 class HomeScreen extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
     <Container>
         <Content contentContainerStyle={{alignItems:'center', justifyContent:'center',top:150}}>
             <Image style={{height:200, width:200, alignSelf:"center"}} source={require('../../assets/imgs/logo.jpg')}/>
         </Content>
         <Content>
          <Form>
            <Item stackedLabel>
              <Label>Username</Label>
              <Input onChangeText={(text=>this.setState({userName:this.props.userName}))}/>
            </Item>
            <Item stackedLabel last>
              <Label>Password</Label>
              <Input onChangeText={(text=>this.setState({passWord:this.props.passWord}))} />
            </Item>
            <Button 
                onPress={()=>this.props.userLogin()}
                style={{width:'80%', alignSelf:'center',margin:20}} iconLeft block>
                <Text style={{color:'white', fontSize:16}}>Sign In</Text>
            </Button>

          </Form>
        </Content>
     </Container>
    );
  }
}
export default HomeScreen
```

i've set it to get the value when the form is submitted, but on submit anything happens.
Please any help on how to get it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're setting the state of your child component, not the parent. You could pass another callback function as a prop, so that the call to this.setState happens within your parent component, not the child.

**Parent:**

```
setUserName = (userName) => {
    this.setState({ userName: userName })
}
setPassWord= (passWord) => {
    this.setState({ passWord: passWord})
}
```

inside render():

```
<HomeScreen
    userLogin = {this.userLogin} 
    userName = {this.state.userName} 
    passWord =  {this.state.passWord}
    setUserName = {this.setUserName}
    setPassWord = {this.setPassWord}
/>
```

**and in child:**

```
<Input onChangeText={this.props.setUserName}/>
...
<Input onChangeText={this.props.setPassWord}/>
```

Also, this call to setState:

```
this.setState({ userName: this.props.userName })
```

Won't do much as it just sets the state to the same value as it already has. You probably want to set it to the new value.